# Expectation value of an estimator

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

In wikipedia the following example is given about what an estimator is and what the estimand is:
"For example, the sample mean is a commonly used estimator of the population mean. "

estimator=sample mean

population mean= the estimand

value of the estimator = estimate

Now, what does it mean to find the expectation value of the estimator?

If the estimator, in the above example is the sample mean, then when we want to find the expectation value of the estimator, we want to find the expectation value of the mean? What does this even mean? How can we find the expectation value of the mean of a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value is with respect to the *sampling distribution* of the sample mean. To explain what that is, fix some population, and imagine you could repeatedly sample from that population. For each sample, calculate the sample mean. Then you get some distribution of sample means which is called the sampling distribution. The expected value of the sample mean with respect to that distribution is what you seek.

Specifically, suppose we draw data independently $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We know $\sigma^2$, but don't know $\mu$, and want to estimate it. Then a natural estimator of $\mu$ is the sample mean $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$. What is the distribution of this estimator? Well, since each $y_i$ is drawn from a normal distribution, the sample mean is a sum of normally distributed random variables, which is itself normally distributed. But with what mean and variance? The expected value is

\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}(\bar{x}) &= \mathrm{E}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathrm{E}(x_i) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} n \mu = \mu.
\end{align}

Note that in the last line I used the fact that the draws are identically distributed. So the expected value of the estimator is the population mean. This is good because in expectation, as we sample over and over again, the sample mean will give us the correct answer. The variance is

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(\bar{x}) &= \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathrm{Var}(x_i) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2} n \sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.
\end{align}

Thus, $\bar{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. This is the sampling distribution of the sample mean. Note that in the second line I used that the draws are independent, and in the third line that they are identically distributed.

Note that not all estimators have the property that their expected value is equal to the population parameter you are trying to estimate (take for example the estimator that always outputs the number $1$). The estimators that *do* have this property are called *unbiased*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if we would summarize this, then: We have a population with values belonging to a physical quantity that characterizes this population, i.e height,weight etc. We want to find the mean of the population (estimand), and the estimator is the sample mean. For each mean, the estimator gives us a value, then we consider N samples of this population, and we have a sample of sample means(sampling distribution). We find the expectation value of the sample mean a.k.a expectation value of the estimator, this is the estimate to the parameter of the population. Did I understand all of this correctly?

Comment: And can i also say: the sampling distribution of the sample mean=mean of the population ?

Comment: Almost correct. The estimate is still the sample mean, not the expected value of it (which depends on parameters you want to estimate in the first place). Also, the *expected value* of the sampling distribution of the sample mean = mean of the population.

Comment: So the estimate is related or tied to ONE sample mean? And I assume if I would extend this in the following way: expected value of the sampling distribution of the sample mean = mean of the population=expectation value of the estimator. I would be correct or no?

Comment: Yep, it's just one sample mean. In reality, we usually cannot resample in the way I described. And yes, then you'd be correct.